# Searchview doesn't work since app compat

Tags: java, android, search, menu, android-appcompat

Since I implented app compat my searchview doesn't work anymore:

```
 Process: com.laurenswuyts.witpa, PID: 26666
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
            at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.Activities.Events.EventActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(EventActivity.java:75)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2820)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:459)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

So nullpointer for searchview while I have it:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.event_main, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And in my menu I have this:

```
<!-- Search Widget -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work anymore but it happened since I started using app compat 21.

Regards,

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Try using the custom `app` namespace for your `actionViewClass` too:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: Wow that worked, can u explain to me why I have to use app instead of android?

Comment: @Laurenswuyts since you started using the support library, some attributes now have to be defined with a custom namespace. You have that namespace defined in your menu file. Some more info can be found in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr).

Comment: I use app: namespace, and it worked on debug version, but it causes the same error in release mode when I have minifyEnabled true in gradle.build, any suggestion?

Comment: @ Ashraf Alshahawy ...use -keep class android.support.** { *; } in progaurd-rules in case of minifyEnabled true

Answer (score 40):

Add the following line to ***proguard-rules.pro*** file located inside ***app*** folder:

> -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

Answer (score 15):

This could also happen if you have proguard enabled and it is striping aways `SearchView` class. You would need to modify proguard settings to keep the class.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136032/action-bar-search-view-android-null-error) question for more details.

Answer (score 12):

It´s an additional information to Simas answer. I found this in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400808/4949671) and it was very important for solving my exception:

> Notice that, it is, `app:actionViewClass` **NOT**
>   `android:actionViewClass`

Answer (score 10):

after a while of playing "run & error" I found a solution.. Looks like the UI-element isn't the reason what causes the error. After setting the search to the QueryListener it is working well. Here is some code:

**Activity** which contains the SearchBar:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit ");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange ");
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                      android:label="@string/app_name"
                                      android:hint="@string/search_hint"/>
```

And the "SearchBar" in **menu.xml**

```
     <item
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="@string/search_title"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

...
```

And last, but not least, the **manifest** (but this should be clear)...

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

more information -> [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you use **progurd** then you have to add the following line into  **proguard-rules.pro** file

> -keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

or

> -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

Answer (score 1):

If if you minify in your build types like that then you need to add a single line your 'proguard-rules.pro' file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Add line your 'proguard-rules.pro' file.

> ```
> -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

After you've clicked on a result, your app is expecting that an operation has not completed and is trying to go further into an Intent argument.

`SearchView.OnSuggestionListener` and return `true` which notifies your app that the click operation has completed.

```
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs if Proguard is enabled.
can be fixed by adding this to proguard rules

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty similar issue with `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`, but different cause. The crash occurs on an action button click

```
 Process: hotspotshield.android.vpn, PID: 26089
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getPadding(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.adjustDropDownSizeAndPosition(SearchView.java:1373)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$4.onLayoutChange(SearchView.java:380)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20690)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
```

The cause is missing attribute `android:popupBackground` in the theme. Actually material AppCompat themes has the required background, but despite my theme extends from `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, it still crashes.
The only solution i have found is to override the attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:popupBackground" tools:ignore="PrivateResource">@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult</item>
</style>
```

It is the default drawable which is used in AppCompat. It is marked as private, but you may use it though. Or declare background drawable by yourself

Answer (score 0):

in my case, this issue occur after migrate my project to AndroidX.
so replace `this: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`
by this: `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`