# Null Pointer in SearchView AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I am just a beginner and i searched this question here found 4-5 question but that did not helped me.I just trying searchView in Actionbar, My activity is AppCompatActivity my code is below.I am using toolbar in this activity. and using this [library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager) too.
OncreatOptionMenu:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager SManager =  (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchViewAction = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(SManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="action_search"
    MainActivity:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    MainActivity:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

and logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at algonation.com.spm.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:183)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:277)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:84)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:251)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:84)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:449)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:66)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If you need whole code of MainActivity please let me know.. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: This is right answer for your question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049294/searchview-doesnt-work-since-app-compat][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049294/searchview-doesnt-work-since-app-compat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting **NullPointerException** because below line is returning null.

> SManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()

You need to

> 1 - Declare the activity(which needs to perform search) to accept the **ACTION_SEARCH** intent, in an <***intent-filter***> element.
>
> 2 - Specify the **searchable** configuration to use, in a <***meta-data***> element.

Assuming you are performing search in your **MainActivity** (which is **AppCompatActivity** as you want) see the below **example**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchViewAction = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(searchMenuItem);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager 
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
    searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
    searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

> **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
          </intent-filter>

          <meta-data
               android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>

</application>
```

> **menu/activity_main.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
```

> **res/xml/searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Hope it will solve your problem & for reference [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

Comment: its working but the search interface is always open. unlike.. first  we click than it opens for input

Comment: If you want to open search interface after click then replace searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(false); with true in above code present inside MainActivity's onCreateOptionsMenu().

Comment: would you please have a look on it [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707277/background-color-or-images-shuffling-on-scrolling-in-recyclerview). I do not want to change my adapter for now. i have same adapter as in this question.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is half old, but the responses don't worked for me.
What worked for me was change the "app" for "appcompat".

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just make sure you are importing "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" and NOT "android.widget.SearchView"

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
```