# changing imageview's color in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview for listify my data, and i have requirement to add any item to user's favourite list, so i am using a png imageview in adapter's view, but whenever i click the imageview to add the item in my favourite list, the color of all images changes. but i want to change just the clicked imageview's color.
here is my code.

```
public class TopTwentyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopTwentyAdapter.mViewHolder> {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final List<TopTwentyModel> mModels;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private String url = "http:";

public TopTwentyAdapter(Context context, List<TopTwentyModel> models) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mModels = models;
}

@Override
public mViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.twenty_list, parent, false);


    return new mViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final mViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final TopTwentyModel model = mModels.get(position);
    holder.bind(model);
    holder.frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView24);
            String s = textView.getText().toString();
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(s);
            final TopTwentyModel model = mModels.get(pos);
            Intent intent = new Intent(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), OfferDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", model.getId());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mModels.size();
}

public class mViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private final TextView txtViewTitle, subtitle, brandid;
    private final NetworkImageView thumbnail;
    private final RelativeLayout frame;
    private final TextView data;
    private final ImageView clip;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private CardView cardview;
    //private MaterialRippleLayout  ripple;

    public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttitle_toptwenty);
        subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_toptwenty);
        thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_topwenty);
        frame = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layer);
        brandid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerid);
        cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        data = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        clip = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_fav);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(AppController.getInstance().getAssets(), "font/trebuc.ttf");
        subtitle.setTypeface(face);
        txtViewTitle.setTypeface(face);
        //ripple=(MaterialRippleLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ripple);

        clip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Resources res = AppController.getInstance().getResources();
                final Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_clipped_32);
                drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                clip.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(TopTwentyModel model) {

        data.setText(model.getFakeId());

        String hexColor = (String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & model.getColor())));

        frame.setBackgroundColor(model.getColor());
        subtitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        txtViewTitle.setText(model.getSubtitle());

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        String full_Url = "http://" + model.getBrandimage();
        thumbnail.setImageUrl(full_Url, imageLoader);


    }
}
```

Comment: This whole questions is related to [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707277/background-color-or-images-shuffling-on-scrolling-in-recyclerview).

Comment: You could have at least posted the whole code of your `ViewHolder`. Without the whole code I can just guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: ok please wait im just posting it Posted. please have a look.

Comment: Just as I suspected, look at my answer, its the solution to your problem.

Comment: check my answer. as couldn't post more code in comments, will be removed after solving issue.

Comment: Look at my answer. You did it wrong. The field `private TopTwentyModel topTwentyModel` is supposed to be in the `ViewHolder`, not the `Adapter`. And just a tip: Don't nest the `ViewHolder` implementation in the `Adapter`. This just clutters your code and causes errors just like this one. The `ViewHolder` and `Adapter` should be completely separate.

Comment: @XaverKapeller i tried to do like you but can't getting the result.

Comment: please see the code above

Comment: @DevendraSingh You can't just edit the post of someone else like that. If you have a problem which you can't manage to solve yourself then ask a new question.

Comment: actually we are working on same issue. at one place.in one company.

Comment: @DevendraSingh Does not matter. You can't just do that. I rolled the edit back. If you have a new problem then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is simple: You are setting the background to the `View` directly. **NEVER** do that. Modify your model and then use one of the `notify...()` methods to tell the `Adapter` it should update the `View` at that position.

The code you posted does not include the whole implementation of the `Adapter`, but I assume that you set the color in `onBindViewHolder()` as well? Since you call `notifyItemChanged()` the model at that position will be rebound and the color you set will be overwritten to the old one.

---

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final View mSomeView;

    private ExampleModel mCurrentModel;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mSomeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.someView);

        mSomeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Here we change the background saved in the current model and notify the `Adapter` that the model has changed.
                mCurrentModel.setBackgroundResourceId(R.drawable.someOtherBackground);
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(ExampleModel model) {
        mCurrentModel = model;
        // In the bind method we set the background the appropriate `View`.
        mSomeView.setBackgroundResource(model.getBackgroundResourceId());
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to do vice versa also. like i added an item in favourite list, i can remove it too. onClick.

Comment: That can be done easily, you just have to implement the appropriate logic in the click listener.

Comment: ok. so the two methods `setBackgroundResourceId(Drawable  drawable)` and `get...()` have to create in model class right. and return value will be integer. in `bind()` i have to give the default view of the image. and in `onClick` have to change the image right?

Comment: In the click listener you modify the model, more specifically the field which stores the background, in bind you set the values from the model to the views. Every time you modify the model you need to call a `notify...()` method to tell the `Adapter` that the `View` which belongs to the model at the supplied position needs to be updated.

Comment: for modify the model i have to pass the resId. for that i have to do like `Modelclass mModel=new Modelclass();` but i have to pass the params if i do like this. should i have to create an empty constructor in modelclass? would you please do more simply the answer.

Comment: Why would have to create a new model? if you create a new model then it won't work. Just modify that one field, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: And what kind of more "simple" answer do you want? It is already as simple as it gets, this whole topic is pretty easy.

Comment: In my question i have `TopTwenty` as model class and in my fragment i pass the data for adapter as you see. now if i do like `TopTwenty model = new TopTwenty()` but here it asks for the params. **simple** means would you add my code in your answer please.

Comment: @Akshaychauhan no that wound be doing the work for you. You are not supposed to create a new instance of your model classes, for this to work you have to modify the current model. Why can't you just do that? Are the fields in your model `final`? If yes then just remove the `final`.

Comment: Yes i am just near to achieve that but please tell me how can i `setBackgroundResourceId()` mean to say which model i created the methods one sets and gets. i can getter by writing `model.getBackgroundRes()`  I declared the ` priavte TopTwenty toptwenty;` this way i am getting `null pointer` the declaration.

Comment: Look at the example in my answer. I have a field in the `ViewHolder` called mCurrentModel and I set the model to it in `bind()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same drawable in multiple places in the list, and want to do somem modifications on a single image ONLY, you need to call "mutate()" on that drawable first, because by defautlt Drawables share state!

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(pImageView.getDrawable().mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(pImageView.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```