# Issue with RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This image explain my question

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl27Y.png)

I have a small issue with recycler view adapter, i have two button up vote and down vote, which toggles onclick, but when i click up vote for example it changes the color of the drawable on the image, but the on click affects other up vote button in other cards. This is the code am using for toggle.

```
boolean up, down, bookmark = false;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!up){
                holder.upvote.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                holder.downvote.setColorFilter(null);
                holder.downCount.setText("0");
                holder.upCount.setText("1");

                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            else{
                holder.upvote.setColorFilter(null);
                holder.downCount.setText("0");
                holder.upCount.setText("0");
                up = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

this is the whole adapter class

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RealmBaseRecyclerViewAdapter<NewsTrend, NewsAdapter.PostsViewHolder> {

public RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults;
public Context context;
public EventListener eventListener;

 static boolean up, down, bookmark = false;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setEventListener(EventListener eventListener) {
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
}

@Override
public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_news_list_items, viewGroup, false);
    PostsViewHolder mediaViewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(v);
    return mediaViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final NewsTrend postsData = getItem(position);

    String eventName = postsData.getTitle();
    String eventDate = postsData.getTimestamp();




    Spanned decodedTitle = Html.fromHtml(eventName);

    if(postsData.getType().equals("bella")){
        holder.sourceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bella);
    }else if(postsData.getType().equals("punch")){
        holder.sourceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.punch);
    }else if(postsData.getType().equals("linda")){
        holder.sourceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.lib);
    }

    holder.eventName.setText(decodedTitle);
    holder.startEvent.setText(getSplitDate(eventDate));
    holder.eventDescription.setText(postsData.getHref());
    holder.sourceName.setText(postsData.getType());

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(postsData.getImage())
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.tw_logo)
                .into(holder.mDisplayGeneratedImage);

    /*Animation animation;
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
    holder.postContentHolder.startAnimation(animation);*/

    holder.postContentHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            new FinestWebView.Builder(context)
                    .theme(R.style.FinestWebViewTheme)
                    .titleDefault("What's Trending")
                    .showUrl(false)
                    .statusBarColorRes(R.color.bluePrimaryDark)
                    .toolbarColorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
                    .titleColorRes(R.color.finestWhite)
                    .urlColorRes(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                    .iconDefaultColorRes(R.color.finestWhite)
                    .progressBarColorRes(R.color.PrimaryDarkColor)
                    .stringResCopiedToClipboard(R.string.copied_to_clipboard)
                    .stringResCopiedToClipboard(R.string.copied_to_clipboard)
                    .stringResCopiedToClipboard(R.string.copied_to_clipboard)
                    .showSwipeRefreshLayout(true)
                    .swipeRefreshColorRes(R.color.bluePrimaryDark)
                    .menuSelector(R.drawable.selector_light_theme)
                    .menuTextGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
                    .menuTextPaddingRightRes(R.dimen.defaultMenuTextPaddingLeft)
                    .dividerHeight(0)
                    .gradientDivider(false)
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.hold, R.anim.hold, R.anim.slide_down)
                    .show(postsData.getHref());
        }
    });



    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = postsData.getHref();
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, postsData.getTitle());
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        }
    });


    holder.upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!up){
                holder.upvote.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                holder.downvote.setColorFilter(null);
                holder.downCount.setText("0");
                holder.upCount.setText("1");

                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            else{
                holder.upvote.setColorFilter(null);
                holder.downCount.setText("0");
                holder.upCount.setText("0");
                up = false;
            }
        }
    });

    holder.downvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!down){
                holder.downvote.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                holder.upvote.setColorFilter(null);
                holder.downCount.setText("1");
                holder.upCount.setText("0");
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            else{
                holder.downvote.setColorFilter(null);
                holder.downCount.setText("0");
                holder.upCount.setText("0");
                down = false;
            }
        }
    });


    holder.bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!bookmark){
                holder.bookmark.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                bookmark = true;
            }else{
                holder.bookmark.setColorFilter(null);
                bookmark = false;
            }
        }
    });



}

@Override
public NewsTrend getItem(int i) {
    return realmResults.get(i);
}

public void swapData(RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults) {
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return realmResults.size();
}

public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout postContentHolder;

    public RobotoTextView startEvent;
    public RobotoTextView eventName;
    public RobotoTextView eventDescription;
    public RobotoTextView sourceName;

    public TextView upCount;
    public TextView downCount;

    public ImageButton share;
    public ImageButton upvote;
    public ImageButton downvote;
    public ImageButton bookmark;

    public ImageView sourceImage;
    public ImageView mDisplayGeneratedImage;

    PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        postContentHolder = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_holder);
        startEvent = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_start);
        eventName = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        eventDescription = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_description);
        mDisplayGeneratedImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlv_name_view);
        share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
        sourceName = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
        sourceImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceImg);
        upvote = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.upVote);
        downvote = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downVote);
        upCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.upCount);
        downCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downCount);
        bookmark = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
    }
}

public interface EventListener {
    void onItemClick(final View view, NewsTrend postsData);
}


public String getSplitDate(String dateString){

    String[] parts = dateString.split("T");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // 004

    return part1;
}
```

}

Comment: where are you getting the data for the `Adaptor` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please explain more

Comment: i don't get, probably i should add the full class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background color or Images shuffling on scrolling in recyclerview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707277/background-color-or-images-shuffling-on-scrolling-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K the adapter is an array of views that inflates on a recycler view, but on click on one of the views its affects another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTag() to identify which item is clicked, Copy this code

```
boolean up, down, bookmark = false;

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.upvote.setTag(holder); // set tag to get clicked item view
            holder.upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PostsViewHolder viewHolder =(PostsViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    if(!v.isChecked()){ // I assume upvote is checkbox
                        viewHolder.upvote.setChecked(true)
                        viewHolder.upCount.setText("1");
                    }
                    else{
                       viewHolder.upvote.setChecked(false)
                        viewHolder.upCount.setText("0");
                    }
                }
            });

                holder.downvote.setTag(holder); // set tag to get clicked item view
                holder.downvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PostsViewHolder viewHolder =(PostsViewHolder) v.getTag();
                        if(!v.isChecked()){ // I assume upvote is checkbox
                            viewHolder.downvote.setChecked(true)
                            viewHolder.downCount.setText("1");
                        }
                        else{
                           viewHolder.downvote.setChecked(false)
                            viewHolder.downCount.setText("0");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

**below method is importent for your problem in adapter class**

```
@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) { 
        return position; 
}
```

**Edit**

```
<CheckBox 
 android:id="@+id/upvote"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:button="@drawable/uvselector" />
```

where `drawable/uvselector.xml` like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR DISABLED UPVOTE IMAGE" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR UPVOTE IMAGE" />
</selector>
```

where `drawable/dvselector.xml` like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR DISABLED DOWNVOTE IMAGE" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/YOUR DOWNVOTE IMAGE" />
</selector>
```

Comment: i want to use this code, but i don't have the v.isChecked() method, the view is a button, how can i work with button.

Comment: use checkbox instade imagebutton & create selector for image on checkbox search on google for create selector file it is very easy

Comment: I have edited answer respective to checkbox u need to set upvote & downvote as checkbox its working fine for me

Comment: Got how to the checkbox image stuff, one more thing, i will use the same code above to achieve the same purpose for every checkbox, set tag on each holder?

Comment: Images will be placed in selector files for upvote & downvote checkbox, setTag() for upvote & downvote checkbox same as above

Comment: Thanks very much, i really appreciate your fast response, i don't know if i could reach you privately some time.

Comment: Today while checking my app, i realize i still have the same issue, on check of one, some of other cards checkbox  of the RecyclerView also responds to the click, still using your the code you provided, please help!

Comment: Thanks it worked! One more thing, switching between the up vote and down vote, both cannot be true at the same time, either false && false or true or false, i couldn't figure that part.

Comment: Thanks it worked now...i have accepted  it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since recyclerView Items are recycled, you need to reset the state of the card everytime. In onBindViewHolder() reset all your views first to initial state and then do set other data. Like :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    resetViews(); // this method resets all your view to initial state you want
    setData(); // Setting current item data.
}
```