# Android SearchManager is null in Instant App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm using a simple search dialog that works fine in the installable app, but I'm getting a NullPointerException only when running the code as an Instant App:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.app.SearchableInfo
>   android.app.ISearchManager.getSearchableInfo(android.content.ComponentName)'
>   on a null object reference

All code and resources are inside the base module.

This happens inside onCreateOptionsMenu in my launcher activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_entity, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

This is the menu.xml file (using appcompat):

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

The searchable.xml file is as follows, just in case:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Activity in Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".EntityActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

The installable app works fine. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: which manifest defines searchable?

Comment: @dazza5000 It's the base module manifest. Thanks for checking the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049294/searchview-doesnt-work-since-app-compat

Comment: @noogui Similar, but not really. That question is about a NPE on the SearchView itself, not on the SearchManager, as is my case. Also, I'm only having problems with Instant Apps. The whole code works fine if it's run from a regular installable APK.

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72685123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to update your Google Play services for Instant Apps for pre-Odevices.**

On your device:

1. go to `Settings` **>** `Apps` **>** `Google Play services for Instant Apps` **>** `Uninstall`
2. A notification should prompt you to you to restore it **>** `restore it`

This should update it the latest version which should no longer cause this crash, currently at `2.11-release-183080821`.

**Note:-** Unfortunately, this does **not apply to emulators** as of now, Android Studio will install the out-of-date version to it.